# Real-time Django.comments

Tags: django

Как сделать Real-time Django.comments? Есть какие-нибудь наработки?

Comment: Мне нужно сделать чистый real-time, например, с node.js. Ajax - делает слишком много запросов к серверу, если много посещений, сервер начинает тормозить. Websockets - хорошая штука, но работает фактически только с двумя браузерами.

Comment: Ну на счет двух браузеров - это нативные вебсокеты, а есть еще библиотечки, например Socket.IO. Они поддерживают почти все браузеры. Кстати, любой современный браузер уже должен поддерживать и нативные сокеты.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, firefox и Opera отключили у себя поддержку websockets по-умолчанию из-за проблем с безопасностью.

Answer (score 1):

Делаете обычные комментарии, раз в несколько секунд запрашиваете ajax'ом новые (вызываете какой нибудь свой метод) и показываете их на страничке. Или я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: Как писали выше, слишком большая нагрузка на сервер. Вы сами представьте: периодические запросы к базе от каждого(!) посетителя.  
Может как-то связать сигналы создания коммента с их отображением? Хотя не совсем четко представляю себе этот механизм.

Comment: Тогда Comtet. Почитайте http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/104945/ и посмотрите Hookbox http://labs.gameclosure.com/hookbox/ и Orbited http://labs.gameclosure.com/orbited2/.

Comment: А с node.js ничего нельзя придумать?